# Windows: git commit -a sends wrong networked drive path to editor

Tags: git-for-windows

With the repo on Windows networked drive, "git commit -a" sends the wrong path to the text editor.

When the repo is on an internal drive, "git commit -a" works as expected, the text editor is opened with Repo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG, and git waits until the file is edited, saved and the editor is closed.

But for a repo on a networked drive, git sends to the editor the path

```
\\readyshare\USB_Storage\Repo\readyshare\USB_Storage\Repo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

which is wrong. This should have been

```
\\readyshare\USB_Storage\Repo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

Or equivalently git using the windows path

```
Z:\Repo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

This happens both on W7 and W10, git version 2.39.0.windows.2 (and earlier).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Doing 'git commit -am "Commit message"'. works fine irrespective of whether the repo is on internal drive or networked drive.

Comment: You should probably file an issue with the git-for-windows folks [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues) (but check to see if there's already one filed, of course).

Comment: That said, and noting that I never use Windows myself if I can possibly avoid it (so perhaps network shared drives work there), I've found Git to be *far* more reliable when used on local file systems. There are numerous (and good) internal-to-Git reasons for this. I'd suggest that you avoid using Git on networked file systems even if it *seems* to work, as the kinds of problems that occur are sporadic but pretty nasty when they do occur.

Answer (score 0):

After some interaction on github (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4207) it turned out that the issue was not with git, but with the editor I set as core.editor, TextPad 6.